# How to stetch li on ul at sidebar menu?

Tags: html, css

So i have simple ul list. What should i do to make li hold 100% width of ul? Please, help! I tried to use flex-basis and flex-drow but it didn't help. And also it should be done at pure CSS.

```css
body{
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}
.container{
    display: flex;
}
.navigation{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    width: 20vh;
    height: 100vh;
    text-align:justify;
}
ul li{
border: 1px solid blue;
position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    
}
ul{
    border: 1px solid blue;
    height: 60vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="contaniner first">
        <div class="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>
                <li>4</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: I’m guessing you might want to start by overwriting the default `padding-left` applied to the `ul` element from your browser default stylesheet.

Comment: Downvote for that _“let me ask questionlet me ask questionlet me ask question[…]”_ stuff at the end, just FYI. If you get a message saying that the text to code ratio in your question is off - then you should fix that by adding to your actual explanation of the problem, and not just try and weasel your way around it by appending repeated gibberish.

Comment: thanks. It was so obvious)

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid blue;
 }
 
 li {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>1</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: no. LI should take all witdth of block( even left side)

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="contaniner first">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>
                <li>4</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}

nav ul{
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display:flex;
    padding:5px;
}

nav ul li{
    border: 1px solid red;
    text-align: center;
    list-style:none;
    width:100%;
}
```

You can remove the `display:flex` as you want and it will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You must remove the padding from **ul** tag.

```css
 body{
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}
.container{
    display: flex;
}
.navigation{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    width: 20vh;
    height: 100vh;
    text-align:justify;
}
ul li{
border: 1px solid blue;
position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    
}
ul{
    border: 1px solid blue;
    height: 60vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    }
 
ul{
 padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="contaniner first">
        <div class="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>
                <li>4</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**i try to solve your question here is your answer......**

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>title</title>

    <style>
        body{
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}
div .container{
    display: flex;
}
div .navigation{
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    text-align:justify;
}
ul li{
border: 1px solid blue;
position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 20vh;
    height: 10vh;
}
ul{
    display: flex;

    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="contaniner first">
        <div class="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>
                <li>4</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</html>
```